# Apache Karaf, can't inject entity manager

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, persistence, apache-karaf

I want to use entity manager from container, but when I try to access it I get

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Need active coordination

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="data-point" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=dvdrental)</jta-data-source>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
</properties>
```

bluprint.xml

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd"
       default-activation="eager"
       xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.2.0"
       xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v2.0.0">

<jpa:enable />
<tx:enable-annotations />
<service id="filesEntityManager" ref="filesEntityManagerImpl" interface="ru.bia.karaf.dao.FilesEntityManager"/>
<bean id="filesEntityManagerImpl" class="ru.bia.karaf.dao.FilesEntityManagerImpl"/>
<bean id="testBean" class="ru.bia.karaf.web.TestBean" init-method="test">
    <property name="filesEntityManager" ref="filesEntityManagerImpl"/>
</bean>
```

TestBean.java

```
public class TestBean {
    private FilesEntityManagerImpl filesEntityManager;

    public void test(){
    System.out.println("hey bro from init");
    System.out.println("filesEntityManager = " + filesEntityManager);
    System.out.println("filesEntityManager.getEm() = " + filesEntityManager.getEm());
}

public FilesEntityManagerImpl getFilesEntityManager() {
    return filesEntityManager;
}

public void setFilesEntityManager(FilesEntityManagerImpl filesEntityManager) {
    this.filesEntityManager = filesEntityManager;
    }
}
```

FilesEntityManagerImpl.java

```
@OsgiServiceProvider(classes = {FilesEntityManager.class})
@Transactional
public class FilesEntityManagerImpl implements FilesEntityManager {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="data-point")
    EntityManager em;
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EntityManager that is injected into FilesEntityManagerImpl is a thread local proxy of the EntityManager. Its lifecycle is bound to a Coordination.

If you access em outside of a Coordination you get this error. You can make sure a Coordination is active by using the @Transactional annotations. If you
do not need an actual transaction but only the Coordination then use @Transactional(TxType.SUPPORTS).

You should also generally not access the EntityManager outside of the object that is injected with it.

Comment: So in this case, should @Transactional be added to class TestBean in order to make this work?

Comment: You can add @Transactional to TestBean to make sure you are still in the same transaction .. but still you should not use the EntityManager from FilesEntityManagerImpl.getEm(). Instead if you need it inside TestBean let blueprint inject it there.